# STS not working after I try to install new IBM server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, sts

After trying to install IBM websphere, sts stopped working. spring and Gradle nature is lost for the existing projects. I even removed the new server, still same issue.

Comment: Sounds to be like an incompatibility that occurred under the hood after installing that piece. To further diagnose, you should post more details like the exact STS version that you had, from where you installed which exact extension, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.